# Laravel relationships clarification

Tags: php, laravel

I already did my research and read the laravel documentation, but I really want to get this subject right so I would really appreciate a beginner-friendly explanation.

I have 4 tables like this:

```
*USERS*
-user_id
-username
-role

*PROJECTS*
-proj_id
-proj_title
-client
-created_by

*TASKS*
-task_id
-proj_id
-status
-created_by

*CLIENTS*
-client_id
-client_name
```

My intention is to create relations between these tables, for example, when an user submits a project, get his id and from his id store his name in "created_by", or, when an user submits a TASK, be able to get the PROJECT name by its id.

Something that confuses me is if I need to create the foreign constrains in both tables, so from USERS to PROJECTS and viceversa or only in one of them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create the constraints on the table, but on the classes. Eloquent and Doctrine do everything you need.

I think your question is if you need the create the functions `$this->belongsTo('Class')` and `$this->hasMany('Class', 'class_id')` in all the models. The answer is not always.

You have to ask yourself if you need to use such relationships: for example, a user will need to see all the projects he created (hasMany), and we will need to see who made the projects (belongsTo).
There are other cases where we won't need some relationships (if we don't want comments to appear on the profile of the user, but we need to see who wrote it on the related article, for example), and then you don't write the functions.